# I'm getting an error when I try to submit my iTunes Connect app record form for review

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, phonegap-build, application-loader

I have built a hybrid app with javascript, html and css and am using phonegap build cloud service to package it up.

I am currently trying to submit my app to the app store and not sure If I have done it correctly.

I was filling out the itunes connect "app record" form for submission of my app to the app store and came across where you need to submit your build. Since I'm developing on windows PC I wasn't able to upload the .ipa file there. I saved the form as It was.
I availed of [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) service in order to use Application Loader to upload the ipa file.
The ipa file successfully uploaded in Application Loader and I was told that  I will receive an email when my application has been approved.

I opened up iTunes connect again and pressed "Submit for Review" on the app record form. However I get the error that I need to upload my build.

[image]

When I press the Activity tab (if the same app form) it shows my build there and the time I uploaded it.

[image]

What should I do at this stage? Have I uploaded my build the wrong way (as I did it separate to the form)?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes Connect is notorious for wildly varying processing times.  Sometimes it will process in a few minutes, other times it can take hours.

You probably did everything right, best just sit tight for awhile until it finally processes.  In extreme cases, you might have to upload another build.

Comment: it has processed successfully now... I was wondering will apple allow me to upload another build to overwrite the one I just uploaded? (ie. with the same version number) .. Is this possible? I just wanted to add something into my config file.

Comment: Sure, as long as you haven't submitted for review you can upload and select another build, you just have to have a different build number